# cakephp session flashes not working across controllers

Tags: php, flash, session, cakephp

I have a controller called students. whenever I go to `students/edit`, make a change, save it and redirect to the view then the session flash appears on `student/view` as expected.

However if I can to `targets/edit`, make a change, save it and redirect to students/view then there is no session flash.

I've tried to use CakeSession::write.

this will read and write fine on anything in the students controller. But if a write to the session in the targets controller then it's not available in the students controller.

I have session in the both the helpers and controllers int he app controller and I've checked that /app/tmp is writable by the server.

I have also set

```
Configure::write('Session', array(
'defaults' => 'cake'
));
```

in core.php

I've googled  around and tried everything I can find but seem to be at a loss

Answer (score 0):

In order to display the session flash messages you must need to write

`echo $this->Session->flash()`

in your layout file or view file,

Make sure you've `echo $this->Session->flash()` in your layout or view file that you're using for your controller.

Comment: let me know if you have any query or concern

Comment: Yes I've got $this->session->flash() in my template.

Comment: did you put `echo` in front of `$this->Session->flash()`?,  just try by doing `pr($_SESSION)` in your view file to know any session is there are not.